# VSCODE - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'

Tags: python, dataframe, visual-studio-code, openpyxl

I'm working on VSCode, I have python 3.11.1 (the only one) and openpyxl 3.1.2 using pip install openpyxl and the installation was successful (I already verified it) in a virtual environment, but when I want to import a dataframe to excel with this line of code: `df.to_excel('data.xlsx')` I get this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[13], line 1
----> 1 df.to_excel('data.xlsx')

File c:\Users\kenneth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-    packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:211, in deprecate_kwarg.._deprecate_kwarg..wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    209     else:
    210         kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 211 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File c:\Users\kenneth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:211, in deprecate_kwarg.._deprecate_kwarg..wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    209     else:
    210         kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 211 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File c:\Users\kenneth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:2374, in NDFrame.to_excel(self, excel_writer, sheet_name, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, startrow, startcol, engine, merge_cells, encoding, inf_rep, verbose, freeze_panes, storage_options)
   2361 from pandas.io.formats.excel import ExcelFormatter
   2363 formatter = ExcelFormatter(
   2364     df,
   2365     na_rep=na_rep,
   (...)
   2372     inf_rep=inf_rep,
   2373 )
-> 2374 formatter.write(
   2375     excel_writer,
   2376     sheet_name=sheet_name,
   2377     startrow=startrow,
   2378     startcol=startcol,
   2379     freeze_panes=freeze_panes,
   2380     engine=engine,
   2381     storage_options=storage_options,
   2382 )

File c:\Users\kenneth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py:944, in ExcelFormatter.write(self, writer, sheet_name, startrow, startcol, freeze_panes, engine, storage_options)
    940     need_save = False
    941 else:
    942     # error: Cannot instantiate abstract class 'ExcelWriter' with abstract
    943     # attributes 'engine', 'save', 'supported_extensions' and 'write_cells'
--> 944     writer = ExcelWriter(  # type: ignore[abstract]
    945         writer, engine=engine, storage_options=storage_options
    946     )
    947     need_save = True
    949 try:

File c:\Users\kenneth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py:56, in OpenpyxlWriter.__init__(self, path, engine, date_format, datetime_format, mode, storage_options, if_sheet_exists, engine_kwargs, **kwargs)
     43 def __init__(
     44     self,
     45     path: FilePath | WriteExcelBuffer | ExcelWriter,
   (...)
     54 ) -> None:
     55     # Use the openpyxl module as the Excel writer.
---> 56     from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
     58     engine_kwargs = combine_kwargs(engine_kwargs, kwargs)
     60     super().__init__(
     61         path,
     62         mode=mode,
   (...)
     65         engine_kwargs=engine_kwargs,
     66     )

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

Installation with pip

```
(env) D:\Udemy\BD_Python>pip show openpyxl  
Name: openpyxl 
Version:3.1.2 
Summary: A Python library to read/write Excel 2010 xlsx/xlsm files 
Home-page: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io 
Author: See AUTHORS 
Author-email: charlie.clark@clark-consulting.eu 
License: MIT 
Location: D:\Udemy\BD_Python\env\Lib\site-packages 
Requires: et-xm
```

I already tried reinstalling

Comment: I don't think you have one python version. First stacktrace shows us that you have Python 3.11 under File c:\Users\kenneth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311, and the second one shows the found openpyxl package is in Location: `D:\Udemy\BD_Python\`

Answer (score 0):

> File c:\Users\kenneth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site

> Location: D:\Udemy\BD_Python\env\Lib\site-packages

Obviously, using pip to find the location is not consistent with the python interpreter used to run the file.

You can use **"Ctrl+Shift+P"** and type **"Python: Select Interpreter"** to choose the `(env) D:\Udemy\BD_Python` which you installed the package in.